# click button simulates clicking a dropdown hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, hidden

I do not know if it's possible, but wanted to have a jsp page when loaded uam dropdown does not appear, but when I click a button.

Basically I want a button that makes the select box. that when clicked appear a list "option".

Already experimenting with various js events and jquery but none works. I had a div with `style = "display: none;"` and within the div I have the select. and wanted to show the option only when you click a button. It is possible ?

Thanks for listening

Comment: Please paste code snippet instead of claiming that you "experimented", might be you was close to correct solution

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mySelectbox').hide();

  $('.myButton').click(function(){
    $('.mySelectbox').val(-1); //clear selection of selectbox
    $('.mySelectbox').show(); //show make the magic
  });
});
```

this work for you?